# Cannot display server/user info

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I am new to building a bot with discord.js

I am using the same code from the discordjs.guide site:

```
if (commandName === 'ping') {
    await interaction.reply('Pong!');
} else if (commandName === 'server') {
    await interaction.reply('Server name: ${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}\nCreated on: ${interaction.guild.createdAt}');
} else if (commandName === 'user') {
    await interaction.reply('Your tag: ${interaction.user.tag}\nYour id: ${interaction.user.id}');
}
```

To have a /server or /user command show relevant info, but the output looks like:

MUDBot
BOT
— Today at 1:38 AM

Your tag: ${interaction.user.tag}

Your id: ${interaction.user.id}

MUDBot
BOT
— 10/05/2022

Server name: ${interaction.guild.name}

Total members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}

Created on: ${interaction.guild.createdAt}

So the formatting is fine but it's not actually filling out the information fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put your output between 2 backquotes.

here is an example:

```js
    await interaction.reply(`Your tag: ${interaction.user.tag}\nYour id: ${interaction.user.id}`);
```

Comment: I see so backquotes rather than single quotes. Thank you.